# How to set the small keyboard appearance in swiftUI iPadOS app as default

Tags: ios, keyboard, swiftui, ipados

In iPadOS the keyboard can appear in one of 3 states, the standard full screen width keyboard, the split view keyboard , or the small floating keyboard.

Is there anyway to set this programatically in an app using SwiftUI?

Comment: No, the user is in control over their keyboard configuration, it cannot be changed by apps